# How to invoke most specific version of overloaded method?

Tags: java, dispatch

I have a primitive collision system which checks every pair of objects to see if they are colliding.

```
int size = drawables.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < size; ++j)
    {
        Drawable drawable = drawables.get(i);
        Drawable drawable2 = drawables.get(j);
        if(CollisionDetector.areColliding(drawable, drawable2))
        {
            CollisionHandler.handleCollision(drawable, drawable2);
        }
    }
}
```

The `CollisionDetector` and `CollisionHandler` both have generic and specific versions of their respective functions, e.g.

```
public static boolean handleCollision(Drawable drawable1, Drawable drawable2)
public static boolean handleCollision(Player player, SolidRectangle rectangle)
public static boolean handleCollision(Player player, Snowflake snowflake)
```

where `Player`, `SolidRectangle`, and `Snowflake` all extend `Drawable`. I would like the above loop to call the most specific version of each method available, but currently it will only call the one for the superclass `Drawable`. Is there some way to do this without manually checking what the classes are via `instanceof`?

I could see how this might not be possible from the following example: If `B extends A` and `C extends A` and I write the methods

```
public void foo(A a, C c)
public void foo(B b, A a)
```

then have

```
A objectB = new B();
A objectC = new C();
foo(objectB, objectC);
```

that the call of `foo` would be ambiguous, but I hope someone might have more insight into the matter than I do. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Visitor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) offers an alternative to [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) in Java.

Besides this, there are a few alternatives:

There is an outdated [MultiJava Project](http://multijava.sourceforge.net/) that implemented mutiple dispatch support in Java and there are a couple of other projects out there using reflection to support multimethods in Java: Java [Multimethods](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2006/06/23/multimethods-for-java), [Java Multimethods Framework](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~forax/works/jmmf/). Perhaps there are even more.

You could also consider an alternative Java-based language which does support multimethods, like [Clojure](http://clojure.org/multimethods) or [Groovy](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/multimethods_in_groovy) (these links point to examples).

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that `CollisionHandler.handleCollision(a,b)` is equivalent to `CollisionHandler.handleCollision(b,a)` . Half the problem is solved with normal method dispatch:

```
drawable.handleCollision(drawable2)
```

But getting that right is a bit like trying to implement the (slightly tedious) checks required for `equals()` to work between objects of different types.

Conceptually, you seem to be looking for a way to pick the function to call based on the (unordered) *pair* of runtime types. Something like a `HashMap<Set<Class>,CollisionHandler>`, except last I checked Java didn't support generic generics (and Sets probably aren't that efficient). The most efficient solution along these lines is to populate a `HashMap<ClassPair,CollisionHandlerFunctor>` via reflection (making sure you get both ClassPair(Player.class,Snowflake.class) and ClassPair(Snowflake.class,Player.class), but even then it doesn't seem like it can be very efficient.